Bouncy Castle C# PemWriter.WriteObjects algorithms
is there a list of working algorithm strings for Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl.PemWriter in the method
public void WriteObject(object obj, string algorithm, char\[\] password, SecureRandom random)type here

The only i could find are:

"DES-EDE"
"DES-EDE3"

but I read somewhere that they are deprecated algorithms.
